# When to use useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, and useDebugValue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I cannot understand why the following `useImperativeHandle`, `useLayoutEffect`, and `useDebugValue` hooks are needed, can you give examples when they can be used, but not examples from the documentation please.

Comment: This video can show you how and when use useImperativeHandle https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akeb4SFWcJM

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Allow me to preface this answer by stating that all of these hooks are very rarely used. 99% of the time, you won't need these. They are only meant to cover some rare corner-case scenarios.

---

### `useImperativeHandle`

Usually when you use `useRef` you are given the instance value of the component the `ref` is attached to. This allows you to interact with the DOM element directly.

`useImperativeHandle` is very similar, but it lets you do two things:

1. It gives you control over the value that is returned. Instead of returning the instance element, you explicitly state what the return value will be (see snippet below).
2. It allows you to replace native functions (such as `blur`, `focus`, etc) with functions of your own, thus allowing side-effects to the normal behavior, or a different behavior altogether. Though, you can call the function whatever you like.

There could be many reasons you want might to do either of the above; you might not want to expose native properties to the parent or maybe you want to change the behavior of a native function. There could be many reasons. However, `useImperativeHandle` is rarely used.

> `useImperativeHandle` customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using `ref`

**Example**

In this example, the value we'll get from the `ref` will only contain the function `blur` which we declared in our `useImperativeHandle`. It will not contain any other properties (*I am logging the value to demonstrate this*). The function itself is also "customized" to behave differently than what you'd normally expect. Here, it sets `document.title` and blurs the input when `blur` is invoked.

```js
const MyInput = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('');
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  React.useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    blur: () => {
      document.title = val;
      inputRef.current.blur();
    }
  }));

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      val={val}
      onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const onBlur = () => {
    console.log(ref.current); // Only contains one property!
    ref.current.blur();
  };

  return <MyInput ref={ref} onBlur={onBlur} />;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

### `useLayoutEffect`

While similar to some extent to `useEffect()`, it differs in that it will run after React has committed updates to the DOM. Used in rare cases when you need to calculate the distance between elements after an update or do other post-update calculations / side-effects.

> The signature is identical to `useEffect`, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside `useLayoutEffect` will be flushed synchronously, **before the browser has a chance to paint**.

**Example**

Suppose you have an absolutely positioned element whose height might vary and you want to position another `div` beneath it. You could use `getBoundingClientRect()` to calculate the parent's height and top properties and then just apply those to the top property of the child.

Here you would want to use `useLayoutEffect` rather than `useEffect`. See why in the examples below:

*With `useEffect`: (notice the jumpy behavior)*

```js
const Message = ({boxRef, children}) => {
  const msgRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const rect = boxRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    msgRef.current.style.top = `${rect.height + rect.top}px`;
  }, []);

  return <span ref={msgRef} className="msg">{children}</span>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const boxRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={boxRef} className="box" onClick={() => setShow(prev => !prev)}>Click me</div>
      {show && <Message boxRef={boxRef}>Foo bar baz</Message>}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.msg {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

*With `useLayoutEffect`:*

```js
const Message = ({boxRef, children}) => {
  const msgRef = React.useRef(null);
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const rect = boxRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    msgRef.current.style.top = `${rect.height + rect.top}px`;
  }, []);

  return <span ref={msgRef} className="msg">{children}</span>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const boxRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={boxRef} className="box" onClick={() => setShow(prev => !prev)}>Click me</div>
      {show && <Message boxRef={boxRef}>Foo bar baz</Message>}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.msg {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

### `useDebugValue`

Sometimes you might want to debug certain values or properties, but doing so might require expensive operations which might impact performance.

`useDebugValue` is only called when the React DevTools are open and the related hook is inspected, preventing any impact on performance.

> `useDebugValue` can be used to display a label for custom hooks in React DevTools.

I have personally never used this hook though. Maybe someone in the comments can give some insight with a good example.

Comment: just a question, if i design a reusable component, it contains some child component, and i want to expose a API that can interactive the child component : e.g search function in a grid component and highlight the search result. is it a good reason to use useImperativeHandle

Comment: @user192344 not enough context for me to answer. It's not completely clear what you need. I suggest you post a new question and explain your problem :)

Comment: @user192344 I think what you are describing is more of a Redux type job, where you would pass the dispatch function returned from useReducer( ). When you want to expose a set of functions to manipulate state (think of it like a state API), while useImperativeHandle( ) could work, it's probably not a good practice to use it like that.

Comment: @user192344 If I understand right, this is what you are trying to achieve - You have a `Search` component which is reusable and also there is a child element (say `input`) in it. The reference to that `input` element is used with in the component and you also want to expose this reference out side so that the end user can also access the `input` element instance. If this is the case, then I believe you can use `useImperativeHandle`

Answer (score 21):

### `useImperativeHandle`

`useImperativeHandle` allows you to determine which properties will be exposed on a ref. In the example below, we have a button component, and we'd like to expose the `someExposedProperty` property on that ref:

**[index.tsx]**

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Button from "./Button";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(Object.keys(buttonRef.current)); // ['someExposedProperty']
    console.log("click in index.tsx");
    buttonRef.current.someExposedProperty();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} ref={buttonRef} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**[Button.tsx]**

```
import React, { useRef, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef } from "react";

function Button(props, ref) {
  const buttonRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    someExposedProperty: () => {
      console.log(`we're inside the exposed property function!`);
    }
  }));
  return (
    <button ref={buttonRef} {...props}>
      Button
    </button>
  );
}

export default forwardRef(Button);
```

[Available here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-useimperativehandle-r0icg?file=/src/index.tsx)

### `useLayoutEffect`

This is the same as `useEffect`, but only fires once all DOM mutations are completed. [This article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect) From Kent C. Dodds explains the difference as well as anyone, regarding these two, he says:

> 99% of the time [`useEffect`] is what you want to use.

I haven't seen any examples which illustrate this particularly well, and I'm not sure I'd be able to create anything either. It's probably best to say that you ought to only use `useLayoutEffect` when `useEffect` has issues.

### `useDebugValue`

I feel like [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usedebugvalue) do a pretty good example of explaining this one. If you have a custom hook, and you'd like to label it within React DevTools, then this is what you use.

If you have any specific issues with this then it'd probably be best to either comment or ask another question, because I feel like anything people put here will just be reiterating the docs, at least until we reach a more specific problem.

Comment: Your example of `useImperativeHandle` doesn't work.

Comment: @sawtaytoes when I built it on code sandbox it did work, the accepted answer seems far better received than this one in any case

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` when you need to mutate(change) the DOM generated by React, useful for integrating libraries that mutate the DOM with React.

Comment: The `useImperativeHandle` example it's just missing the correct code in `Table.jsx`, I just copied the snippet you provided and it works. Thanks!

Comment: it's very bad example for imperative handle, because you can just pass ref without it to component, and nothing changing

Comment: @AuthorProxy I've updated the answer to a version of code which is now working. Hopefully you can reconsider your comment slightly - others have found the previous example to be useful, and I find it helpful to try and keep comments strictly constructive

Comment: In my case it says: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'someExposedProperty') and I see your code is working on Sandbox

Answer (score 13):

The `useImperativeHandle` hook helped me a lot with a use case of mine.

I created a grid component which uses a third-party library component. The library itself has a big data layer with built-in functionality that can be used by accessing the instance of the element.

However, in my own grid component, I want to extend it with methods which perform actions on the grid. Furthermore, I also want to be able to execute those methods from outside of my grid component.

This is easily achievable by adding the methods inside of the `useImperativeHandle` hook, and then they will be exposed and usable by its parent.

My grid component looks kind of like this:

```js
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef } from 'react';
import ThirdPartyGrid from 'some-library';

export default forwardRef((props, forwardedRef) => {
    const gridRef = useRef(null);
    useImperativeHandle(forwardedRef,
        () => ({

            storeExpandedRecords () {
                // Some code
            },

            restoreExpandedRecords () {
                // Some code
            },

        }));
    
    return (
        <div ref={forwardedRef}>
            <ThirdPartyGrid 
                ref={gridRef}
                {...props.config}
            />
        </div>
    );
});
```

And then in my parent, I can execute those methods:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Parent () {
    const gridRef = useRef(null);

    const storeRecords = () => {
        gridRef.current.storeExpandedRecords();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        storeRecords();
    }, []);

    return <GridWrapper ref={gridRef} config={{ something: true }} />
};
```

Comment: I used this on a project very similiar use case - full example here  https://github.com/johndpope/grid/blob/main/src/SupabaseGrid.tsx

Comment: @johndpope you used what Supabase built

Comment: yes - but my fork required me to implement useImperativeHandle in order to communicate between components

Answer (score 3):

> **useImperativeHandle**

usually  hook expose your functional based component method and properties to other component by putting functional component inside forwardRef
example

```
const Sidebar=forwardRef((props,ref)=>{

       const [visibility,setVisibility]=useState(null)
       
       const opensideBar=()=>{
         setVisibility(!visibility)
       }
        useImperativeHandle(ref,()=>({
            
            opensideBar:()=>{
               set()
            }
        }))
        
       return(
        <Fragment>
         <button onClick={opensideBar}>SHOW_SIDEBAR</button>
         {visibility==true?(
           <aside className="sidebar">
              <ul className="list-group ">
                <li className=" list-group-item">HOME</li>
                <li className=" list-group-item">ABOUT</li>
                <li className=" list-group-item">SERVICES</li>
                <li className=" list-group-item">CONTACT</li>
                <li className=" list-group-item">GALLERY</li>
             </ul>
          </aside>
         ):null}
        </Fragment>
       )
     }
    
    
    //using sidebar component
```

```
 
class Main extends Component{
    
     myRef=createRef();
    
     render(){
      return(
       <Fragment>
         <button onClick={()=>{
                     ///hear we calling sidebar component
                     this.myRef?.current?.opensideBar()
                    }}>
          Show Sidebar
        </button>
        <Sidebar ref={this.myRef}/>
       </Fragment>
      )
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that there are already answers to this question. So, I just want to share my articles about useImperativeHandle, useEffect, and useLayoutEffect.

I have written an example-based article **aboutuseImperativeHandle** hook, you can check it out here: [useImperativeHandle by Examples](https://ilxanlar.medium.com/useimperativehandle-by-examples-85b753a39c41)

I also wrote an article about **effects in React** which explains **useEffect** hook and **useLayoutEffect** hook differences in detail: [A Beginner’s Guide to Effects in React](https://ilxanlar.medium.com/a-beginners-guide-to-effects-in-react-b7440a596471)