# React Native Maps show marker callout

Tags: react-native, maps, marker

I'm using `react-native-maps` to render GOOGLE MAPS with loads of markers that I fetch from my co-worker's API. Bellow the map I have a `FlatList` rendering data from every marker on the screen. The item in FlatList's `renderItem` is a `TouchableOpacity`. How can I focus on the marker callout when I press the corresponding  button in the list?

ScreenShot:

[image]

code:

```
<Container>
  <StatusBar
    barStyle={theme.colors.statusDark}
    backgroundColor={theme.colors.background1}
  />
  <GoogleMaps>
    {markers.map(marker => (
      <MyMarker
        key={marker.uid}
        identifier={marker.uid}
        markerLatitude={marker.position.lat}
        markerLongitude={marker.position.lng}
        title={marker.name}
        address={marker.address}
        cashback={marker.cashback}
      />
    ))}
  </GoogleMaps>
  <DivisorSimple />
  <ListContainer>
    {fetchIsLoading ? (
      <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
    ) : (
      <FlatList
        data={markers}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <ListMapItem
            handleClick={() => {}
            title={item.name}
            address={item.address}
            cashback={item.cashback}
            handleGetRoute={() => handleGetRoute(item.position.lat, item.position.lng)}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={item => item.uid}
      />
    )}
  </ListContainer>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Animating map to marker is done imperatively, so you need to get a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to your MapView component, e.g. add this prop to MapView:

```
<MapView
  ...
  ref={ref => this.map = ref}
>
  {data.map(item => <Marker ... />)}
</MapView>
```

In easiest case, `this` should refer to the component that is also rendering your Markers, so that you can reference `this.map` in Marker's render. If your MapView component is wrapped into something else, you will need to [forward ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to get the ref to the actual MapView component

Then, you need to keep track of Region currently displayed on a map and it's changes when user moves the camera

```
<MapView
  ...
  onRegionChangeComplete={region => this.setState({ region })}
>
```

After that you can use [MapView's animateToRegion **method**](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#methods) to focus on marker

```
// ListMapItem's handleClick prop
handleClick={() => {
      // construct new region from marker's lat/lng
      // and current region's deltas to keep zoom level
      const newRegion = {
        latitude: item.position.lat,
        longitude: item.position.lng,
        latitudeDelta: this.state.region.latitudeDelta,
        longitudeDelta: this.state.region.latitudeDelta,
      }
      // animate camera to that region over 500 ms
      this.map.animateToRegion(newRegion, 500)
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This will probably work but I'm having trouble forwarding refs in my functional component. Is there any way you can help me?

Comment: Im following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005663/when-to-use-useimperativehandle-uselayouteffect-and-usedebugvalue
But im getting `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`
And it looks like its something with `react-redux`

Comment: Forwarding refs in functional components differs from that in class components. Take a look here https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components

Comment: Sadly I didnt find any solutions at the official docs, and it doesnt even mention useRef hook.

Comment: take a look here if you are using hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref