# Why is useImperitaveHandle hook used in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

I am not able to find a use Case for useImperativeHandle Hook. Trying to Google and understand I came across a code sandbox showing an example of why the useImperitaveHandle Hook would be used. Here is the link to the codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/useimperativehandle-example-forked-illie?file=/src/App.js

I modified the code to get it working without the useImperitaveHandle in the codesandbox link below. Can someone explain why the hook would be used as I believe that code can be written without it to provide the exact same functionality.

https://codesandbox.io/s/useimperativehandle-example-forked-2cjdc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Could that be because of the typo? You inverted the i and a in useImperativeHandle. You can find an explanation there: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle and another SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005663/when-to-use-useimperativehandle-uselayouteffect-and-usedebugvalue

Comment: Can you check again, I couldnt find the typo. Also I read both the docs as well as that SO question. But neither was satisfactory. Can you explain with and example why useImperativeHandle would be needed in the codesandbox link

Comment: You are right that it can often be avoided.  The docs actually advise against using it (and ref forwarding in general) when it’s possible to achieve the same functionality by passing props.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I understand that but there has to be some use case where useImperativeHandle will be irreplaceable and needs to be used, otherwise what is the point of creating it in the first place. I was just trying to find an example of that

Comment: Some UI component libraries use it on inputs, etc.  I think mainly to leave open the possibility that you the user might want to pass a ref through to the underlying DOM element in order to do something custom that the package authors haven’t explicitly planned for.  So they use useImperativeHandle to implement their package functionality with the ref, but ref forwarding allows you to do other things as well.

Comment: @LindaPaiste Ya that makes sense, thats what the documentation and the other SO question also said. I have a somewhat better understanding now. Thanks

Comment: Some usages: [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/search?q=useImperativeHandle&type=), [ant-design](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/search?q=useimperativehandle&type=), [react-spring](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/blob/e666ac8fe53c68cc33ca3b0ab577169a5794f161/packages/parallax/src/index.tsx)

Comment: @LindaPaiste I found a use case with an example where useImperativeHandler cannot be replaced. I will answer my own question to help anyone else who might have a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an example where this would be used. According to my understanding it will be mainly needed if you need to write some custom functionality for a library and will need some of the library's in built features.

In the example I will provide, I will write a custom CellEditor for the library ag-grid(Table library) because I want to select the value of the cell in the table using Material UI's autocomplete. Below is the code

```
import React, { useState, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";

import MuiTextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MuiAutocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

const AutocompleteEditor = forwardRef(
  ({ fieldToSave, fieldToShow, textFieldProps, options, ...props }, ref) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
      return {
        getValue: () => {
          return value;
        },
        afterGuiAttached: () => {
          setValue(props.value);
        },
      };
    });

    const tranformValue = (value, fieldtosave) =>
      Array.isArray(value)
        ? value.map((v) => v[fieldtosave] || v)
        : value[fieldtosave];

    function onChangeHandler(e, value) {
      setValue(value ? tranformValue(value, fieldToSave) : null);
    }

    return (
      <MuiAutocomplete
        style={{ padding: "0 10px" }}
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(item) => {
          return typeof item === "string" || typeof item === "number"
            ? props.options.find((i) => i[fieldToSave] === item)[fieldToShow]
            : item[fieldToShow];
        }}
        getOptionSelected={(item, current) => {
          return item[fieldToSave] === current;
        }}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
        disableClearable
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <MuiTextField
            {...params}
            {...textFieldProps}
            style={{ padding: "5px 0" }}
            placeholder={"Select " + props.column.colId}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }
);

export default AutocompleteEditor;
```

**IGNORE THE AUTOCOMPLETE PART IF ITS CONFUSING, ITS NOT IMPORTANT FOR UNDERSTANDING useImperativeHandler**

So To explain what the code does. The value of the above component is set by Autocomplete by the user, but ag-grid table also needs the value as it needs to update the value in corresponding cell.

It uses a ref internally that it passes to the customCellEditor. The useImperativeHook then tells ag-grid to use the value from the state of the component whenever getValue is called (it is called when the cell needs to display the value)