# How do I call component's inner function from its parent component in React

Tags: reactjs

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  return <Child {...props} />
};

const Child = (props) => {
  function handleClick() {
   ...
  }
  return <div {...props}><a onClick={handleClick}>link</a></div>;
}
```

I want to call the child's `handleClick` function from within its parent component (that has some custom events). My first guess was to use a state in a parent component and invoke the `handleClick` event in a `useEffect` callback:

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  return <Child toggle={toggle} {...props} />
};

const Child = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => { if (toggle) handleClick() }, [toggle]);
  function handleClick() { 
    ... 
  }      
  return <div {...props}><a onClick={handleClick}>link</a></div>;
}
```

However I believe this is not what `useEffect` is created for and is a poor solution all around.

Comment: Is it possible to put the handleClick function in the Parent component, and pass it to Child component?

Comment: @TheKNVB the `handleClick` function contains a bunch of state dependent logic from the Child component, so it's not really possible to move it up the tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, and useDebugValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005663/when-to-use-useimperativehandle-uselayouteffect-and-usedebugvalue)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `handleClick` function in the Parent and also use it in the Child. that way you'll call the same function when you trigger the custom events in the Parent, as well as when you click the Child:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const click = () => {
    console.log("Clicked!");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={click}>Custom event!</button>
      <Child handleClick={click} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = ({ handleClick }) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Hello</button>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lift up your handler function then context API is the solution.